# SQL Report Server Display When Property

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting

In MS Access exist "Display When Property" witch can for one objects on report define where it is going to be displayed (Print Only,Screen Only,Always).
Is there analog function in SSRS2008.
I usually use IIF() in visible properties for conditional showing or hiding data, But i do not know how I can something hide when it is going to print.

EDIT:
Is there a possibility to this be done using C# and ASP.NET technology, or Can I make assembly for this.
If I render page as HTML maybe Ill can be able to hide some labels before printing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, outside a custom rendering extension.

You can certainly use parameters to conditionally suppress various elements, and then provide a custom export/print control to set this parameter in the background. That precludes the use of the Report Manager, but if you are already rolling your own report interface, it wouldn't be much more work.

Comment: Probably will, and I have to create their own environment to run reports. At the beginning I hoped that WEB Report Site will be able to meet my need, but how are things getting knotty I started to add custom labels on Reports witch act like buttons. etc (Go to other report, do the e mail sending, and other) Thins like that I do not wont to display on printed paper. Now I starting with ASP.NET page for handling report viewer and custom buttons for that kind of actions , But staring that I open whole set of new troubles with login, security and fitting reports to WEB page.

Comment: Have you heard of SSRS security extensions? They let you integrate the security mechanism of your website with the report server. Very useful. There are samples on MSDN. Alternatively you can bypass the report server altogether by using "local mode", but that has its own problems. See here for details: http://www.gotreportviewer.com/